# Finding gEDA installation directory

Tags: software-installation

I installed [gEDA](http://www.geda-project.org/) and I am trying to find it's installation directory/path.

I've searched Google for many strings and entered a lot of the results it returned but didn't find anything about that.

So how can I find gEDA's installation directory/path?

---

*Edit (24 May, 16:55 UTC):*

I've tried the following, suggested by [@phunehehe](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/250/phunehehe):

```
$ dpkg-query -L gEDA
/.
/usr
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/geda
```

but it doesn't seem like the installation folder for gEDA, only the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you installed it by the package manager, you can find the files installed like this:

```
# Debian, Ubuntu etc.
dpkg-query -L <package-name>
# Redhat, Centos etc.
rpm -ql <package-name>
```

The package might pull in other packages that you should also check. To find them:

```
# Debian, Ubuntu etc.
apt-cache rdepends <package-name>
# Redhat, Centos etc.
yum resolvedep <package-name>
```

See [Pacman Rosetta](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman_Rosetta) for commands on other distros.

As a last resort (or if you didn't use the package manager, which I strongly recommend against), you can try searching by file name:

```
sudo updatedb
locate --ignore-case <program-name>
```

Comment: Hi thanks, I've tried it (see my edit), but I don't think that this is the path I need.

Comment: Updated to add some more methods.

Comment: Thanks, I found it with the aid of `apt-cache`